# PloneFormGen Refuses to send mail on one site

Tags: plone, mailer, ploneformgen

We have a server running Plone 4 which hosts many of our sites, on one we have just noticed it is not sending any mail from PloneFormGen.

I have tried:

- Recreating the form
- Deleting & recreating the mailer in the form
- Altering the site from address (avoiding any spam issues like sending to and from the same address)

All the other sites on this server can send mail fine from PFG, I am not really sure which log files to check but below is the last few lines of my events.log file which mentions a few things about missing adapters as far as I can tell, can someone translate this form me?:

```
    ------
2012-07-11T15:13:38 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formsavedataadapter.2012-07-03.5018819612' is missing; ignored.
------
2012-07-11T15:13:38 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formmaileradapter.2012-07-11.9678428439' is missing; ignored.
------
2012-07-11T15:13:38 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formmaileradapter.2012-07-11.9935785303' is missing; ignored.
------
2012-07-11T15:13:38 ERROR MailDataManager [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Plone-4.0.4-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/patches/sendmail.py", line 9, in _catch
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.sendmail-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/sendmail/mailer.py", line 46, in send
    connection = self.smtp(self.hostname, str(self.port))
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 547, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
------
2012-07-11T15:13:38 ERROR MailDataManager [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Plone-4.0.4-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/patches/sendmail.py", line 9, in _catch
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.sendmail-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/sendmail/mailer.py", line 46, in send
    connection = self.smtp(self.hostname, str(self.port))
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 547, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
------
2012-07-11T15:30:18 INFO CMFFormController /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.PloneFormGen-1.7a2-py2.6.egg/Products/PloneFormGen/skins/PloneFormGen/fg_base_view_p3.cpt: No default action specified for status success, content type ANY.  Users of IE can submit pages using the return key, resulting in no button in the REQUEST.  Please specify a default action for this case. 

------
2012-07-11T15:30:18 INFO CMFFormController /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.PloneFormGen-1.7a2-py2.6.egg/Products/PloneFormGen/skins/PloneFormGen/fg_embedded_view_p3.cpt: No default action specified for status success, content type ANY.  Users of IE can submit pages using the return key, resulting in no button in the REQUEST.  Please specify a default action for this case. 

------
2012-07-11T15:30:32 INFO CMFFormController /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.PloneFormGen-1.7a2-py2.6.egg/Products/PloneFormGen/skins/PloneFormGen/fg_base_view_p3.cpt: No default action specified for status success, content type ANY.  Users of IE can submit pages using the return key, resulting in no button in the REQUEST.  Please specify a default action for this case. 

------
2012-07-11T15:30:32 INFO CMFFormController /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.PloneFormGen-1.7a2-py2.6.egg/Products/PloneFormGen/skins/PloneFormGen/fg_embedded_view_p3.cpt: No default action specified for status success, content type ANY.  Users of IE can submit pages using the return key, resulting in no button in the REQUEST.  Please specify a default action for this case. 

------
2012-07-11T15:39:18 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formsavedataadapter.2012-07-03.5018819612' is missing; ignored.
------
2012-07-11T15:39:18 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formmaileradapter.2012-07-11.9678428439' is missing; ignored.
------
2012-07-11T15:39:18 WARNING PloneFormGen Designated action adapter 'formmaileradapter.2012-07-11.9935785303' is missing; ignored.
------
2012-07-11T15:39:18 ERROR MailDataManager [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Plone-4.0.4-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/patches/sendmail.py", line 9, in _catch
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.sendmail-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/sendmail/mailer.py", line 46, in send
    connection = self.smtp(self.hostname, str(self.port))
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 547, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
------
2012-07-11T15:39:18 ERROR MailDataManager [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Plone-4.0.4-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/patches/sendmail.py", line 9, in _catch
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.sendmail-3.5.2-py2.6.egg/zope/sendmail/mailer.py", line 46, in send
    connection = self.smtp(self.hostname, str(self.port))
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 547, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I can provide other information please just tell me where to look if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there's not a typo in the mail server name in this site's Mail Settings control panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this site has an incorrect mail server configured at Site Setup>Mail?

Comment: Thank you that resolved the problem. I must have checked it so many times -.-

Answer (score 3):

This traceback means that your server is unable to connect mail server:

```
  gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

It's an operating system levle failure.
DNS resolution of the mail server name failed. The reason could  be

- Firewalled server
- Misconfigured DNS
- or mistyped mail server name as mentioned above

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this did resolve it (typo in mailserver)